# How to print duplicate letters in a string with their count number in C?

Tags: c, c-strings

I have been implemnting an algorithim for counting and printing duplicate letters (two times or more) in a C string.

Example :
If input string was : `"Hello There"`
The output should be :

```
e - 3
h - 2
l - 2
```

My current code has been printing what i need,but it **doesn't consider capital letters**, it also keep giving me the message `stack smashing detected (core dumped)` . So, it doesn't work properly and I'm not sure why :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[10];
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};

   printf("Enter a string of size [10] or less:\n");
   gets(string);

   while (string[c] != '\0')
   {
      /**reading characters from 'a' to 'z' or 'A' to 'Z' only
          and ignoring others */

      if ((string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') || (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z'))

      {
         if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z')
         {
         count[string[c]-'a']++;
         }
         else if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z')
         {
         count[string[c]-'A']++;
         }
      }

      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      /** Printing only those characters
          whose count is at least 2 */

      if (count[c] > 1)
         printf("%c - %d \n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Hello There"` doesn't fit in a character array of size `10`. This is good example of why you should not use `gets`.

Use:

```
fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
```